# How to access a directory in hosts machine from inside a docker container?

Tags: docker, mounted-volumes

I'm using docker version `Docker version 1.9.1, build a34a1d5` on `ubuntu:14.04`. I have created a docker container with a volume option like this `docker run -it -p 80:8080 -v host/folder:container/folder ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash`. `host/folder` has some files that i'm trying to access from `container/folder`. The files from `host/folder` isnt available from `container/folder`.

Answer (score 4):

when you mount a host folder as a volume with `-v` you must specify absolute paths, so replace `host/folder` and `container/folder` with the absolute path.

Something like `docker run -it -p 80:8080 -v /home/uday/host/folder:/container/folder ubuntu:14.04 /bin/bash` (of course set the correct path to your host/folder directory)

Comment: Didn't not work. I have a `VOLUME /home/ubuntu/somefolder` instruction in my Dockerfile to create a volume. I'm using absolute paths for both host folder and inside container also. I'm using `ansible` to deploy containers and I'm passing path to `volumes` argument of `docker_container` module. Is that causing an issue?

Comment: Once the container is spin up with a volume option can we delete and recreate the host folders?

Comment: Both host and container volume have to be absolute, sorry missed in what you originally posted, fixed now above. Not sure what you mean by deleting and recreating host folders. Any changes you make in the contents of the mounted folder will be seen immediately. On the other hand if you completely delete a mounted folder on the host the mount will be broken and I suspect unrecoverable in all cases without shutting down and restarting the container.